# Ember.js modal component - where should I write the openModal action?

Tags: ember.js, modal-dialog

I am trying to setup a modal window as outlined in this post:

```
http://blog.atmartin.io/a-dead-simple-ember-cli-modal/
```

The author indicated that the openModal action is written in the app/controllers/application.js...

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
actions: {
    openModal: function(targetId) {
        var modal = Ember.Views.views[targetId];
        modal.send('toggleModal');
    }
}
});
```

However, I am using the component from the books list page, using a test button:

```
  <button {{action 'openModal' 'modal-author'}}>Open Author Modal Window</button>

 {{#simple-modal enabled=false title="--Simple Modal --" id="modal-author"}}
     Modal text. Oh girl!
 {{/simple-modal}}
```

So, I tried (I may be wrong...) to insert the openModal action (when the button is clicked) into the book.js route:

```
// app/routes/books.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model() {
    return this.store.findAll('book');
},
actions: {
     openModal: function(targetId) {
     var modal = Ember.View.views[targetId];
     modal.send('toggleModal');
  },
  ....
 }
});
```

In this case, I get an error Ember.view seems to be undefined ...

```
books.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'views' of undefined
```

Comment: What Ember version are you using? In the first paragraph of the linked post the author says that this approach doesn't work in recent versions of Ember and includes a link to an updated version.

Comment: thanks a lot .. I miss it... as I jumped directly to the next paragraph...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a tutorial that utilizes a deprecated & removed construct (views) in recent versions of Ember.

I recommend you use the https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog addon for creating modals in recent versions of Ember.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link...  this is a recurrent problem with many tuts when the requirements are not specified ...  as it was using components I guessed it was 2.5-ready